# Password_verify troubles

Tags: php, html, pdo, password-hash

I'm getting troubles with my sign/login `php`system. I use `password_verify()` and `password_hash()` with `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` option.

I'm probably going wrong in my system.

All that I want is to be able to connect to the member space with a first name, last name and password.

Here is my `SQL Table COMPTE`

| id | nom | prenom | motDePasse | email | telephone | typeUtilisateur | cleMDP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | uno | test | 12345678 | 1@m.c | 012345678 | 1 | $2Ydzn |

Here is my `php` code for my signing system

```php
<?php    

/* Connexion à la base de données et gestion des erreurs */
try{
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=ckdhjqodomiform.mysql.db;dbname=ckdhjqodomiform;charset=UTF8", "ckdhjqodomiform", "D0miform01");
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Échec lors de la connexion : ' . $e->getMessage();
}

/* Déclaration des variables pour la création du compte dans la table COMPTE de la base de données*/
$id += 1;
$nom = $_GET['nom'];
$prenom = $_GET['prenom'];
$motDePasse = $_GET['mdp'];

if(!empty($_GET['email'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
} else {
    $email = "NULL";
}

$telephone = $_GET['tel'];

switch ($_GET['typeCompte']) {
    case "S":
        $typeUtilisateur = '1';
        break;
    
    case "P":
        $typeUtilisateur = '2';
        break;
    
    case "E":
        $typeUtilisateur = '3';
        break;
}

$cryptMDP = password_hash($motDePasse, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

/* Préparation de la requête pour éviter les injections SQL dans la base de données via les champs de textes des formulaire*/
$requete = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO COMPTE(id, nom, prenom, motDePasse, email, telephone, typeUtilisateur, cleMDP) VALUES (:id, :nom, :prenom, :motDePasse, :email, :telephone, :typeUtilisateur, :cleMDP)");
$requete->bindParam(':id', $id);
$requete->bindParam(':nom', $nom);
$requete->bindParam('prenom', $prenom);
$requete->bindParam('motDePasse', $motDePasse);
$requete->bindParam('email', $email);
$requete->bindParam('telephone', $telephone);
$requete->bindParam('typeUtilisateur', $typeUtilisateur);
$requete->bindParam('cleMDP', $cryptMDP);

/*Execution du code et creation du compte dans la table COMPTE */
$requete->execute();
?>
```

And my `php` code for the logging system

```php
<?php

/* Connexion à la base de données et gestion des erreurs */
try{
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=ckdhjqodomiform.mysql.db;dbname=ckdhjqodomiform;charset=UTF8", "ckdhjqodomiform", "D0miform01");
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Échec lors de la connexion : '.$e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT nom, prenom FROM COMPTE";
$user = $dbc->query($sql);
$username = $user->fetch();

$motDePasse = $_GET['motDePasse'];
$cryptMDP = $dbc->query("SELECT cleMDP FROM COMPTE WHERE nom=".$username['nom']." AND prenom=".$username['prenom']);
$data = $cryptMDP->fetch();

if (password_verify($motDePasse, $data['cleMDP']) == true) {
    $loginMessage = "Connexion réussie";
} else {
    $loginMessage = "Connexion impossible. Vérifiez vos informations";
}
?>
```

If you can help/show me how to fix my problem, I'd thank you.
(Sorry for my english)

EDIT:
I'll show my form and my logging system.

> loginForm.php

```html
<div class="formulaire">
<form action="./loginCheck.php" method="GET">
    <h3>Connectez-vous</h3>
    <div class="ligne">
        <div class="col25">
            <label for="email"><i class="fas fa-at"></i> Adresse email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col75">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="ex: monadressemail@mail.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ligne">
        <div class="col25">
            <label for="motDePasse"><i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i> Mot de Passe</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col75">
            <input type="password" id="mdp" name="mdp" placeholder="ex: motdepasse123">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ligne">
        <div class="col25">
            <label for="remember" style="font-size: 80%"><i class="fas fa-user-check"></i> Se souvenir de moi</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col75">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="slider"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <button class="valider" type="submit" formaction="./loginCheck.php" formmethod="post"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Se connecter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div style="font-size: 50%">Pas encore de compte ? <a href="inscription">Inscrivez-vous</a></div>
</div>
```

> loginCheck.php

```php
<?php

/* Connexion à la base de données et gestion des erreurs */
try{
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=ckdhjqodomiform.mysql.db;dbname=ckdhjqodomiform;charset=UTF8", "ckdhjqodomiform", "D0miform01");
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Échec lors de la connexion : '.$e->getMessage();
}

$requete = $dbc->prepare("SELECT cleMDP FROM COMPTE WHERE email = :email");
$requete->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$requete->execute();
$ligne = $requete->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$cryptMDP = $ligne['cleMDP'];

if (password_verify($_POST['motDePasse'], $cryptMDP) == true) {
    $loginMessage = "Connexion réussie";
} else {
    $loginMessage = "Connexion impossible. Vérifiez vos informations";
}
?>
```

Comment: What size field is `cleMDP`, also why do you also store the password as clear text (`motDePasse`)?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT nom, prenom FROM COMPTE";
$user = $dbc->query($sql);
$username = $user->fetch();` ...this bit makes no sense. It just gets the first record from the COMPTE table. It's unlikely to to be the record of the current user. What are you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: `cleMDP` is a varchar(255) field type. Also, I store `motDePasse` because I originally wrote the table like this (it's the first time I'm doing signing/logging system, so I don't know how to make it correctly)

Comment: @ADyson I'm just trying to figure out how to logging with a last name, first name and password but in a safe way for the user. I heard about `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: Yes I know, you already said that. But that doesn't answer the specific question I asked you. What are you trying to do with _that specific bit of code_? I would have expected that you have a login form somewhere? In that form, the user should have to enter a username and password. You seem to be trying to read the password from $_GET (which is bad security practice by the way, you should always use POST for login requests), but not the username. In fact your SQL table doesn't even have usernames...don't rely on firstname/lastname, it's too easy for two people to have the same name...

Comment: ...you should make the user create a unique username, or you could use their email address (as many sites do) because that should be unique (and you can check, at registration, whether that email or username has been used before in your database).

Comment: @ADyson I just wrote a fake line in the table to hide my informations because I registered a line with my personnal informations. But for now I'm just testing to get a correct logging (I'm just getting the message that says my informations are incorrect while they're not)

Comment: Ok. But I didn't ask about whether the data you entered was real or not, that's irrelevant. You're still not answering my questions.

Comment: Your system seems totally flawed - you need to have a form which asks for a username (or email) and password. When that form is submitted you need to query the database for a row which matches the username. if you find a matching row, then get the password out of it, and check it with password_verify. If either you don't find a matching row, or the password_verify fails, then return an error message to the user. If it succeeds, log them in.

Comment: @ADyson I just don't get what you mean by "What are you trying to do here exactly ?". I'm trying to compare line in my `COMPTE` table with the informations we submit in the logging form

Comment: `I'm trying to compare line in my COMPTE table with the informations we submit in the logging form`...ok that's the answer I wanted. But...that line of code I highlighted just selects the first user from your table. It doesn't even _try_ to compare it with anything from your form. That was my point. It makes no sense

Comment: @ADyson Also, I heard I shouldn't use `rowCount()` when using a `SELECT` type request

Comment: Ok I don't know how you think that's relevant to any of this either. But anyway, basically it seems you have a fundamental design flaw because you don't seem to have any kind of username defined. Read this comment, if you don't read any of the others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934556/password-verify-troubles?noredirect=1#comment116577583_65934556

Comment: If (for the sake of argument) we decide to use email as the unique username, then I would be expecting something like this, to try and select a user matching a row in your table: `$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT cleMDP FROM  COMPTE WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST["email"]); $stmt->execute();`. Then you'd get the row returned by that (if any), and use password_verify to compare the password value against $_POST["motDePasse"]. (Note I've assumed you're going to submit your form securely using POST, too).

Comment: `$requete = $dbc->prepare("SELECT cleMDP FROM COMPTE WHERE email = :email"); $requete->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']); $requete->execute();` and `if (password_verify($_POST['motDePasse'], $requete) == true) { $loginMessage = "Connexion réussie" } else { $loginMessage = "Connexion impossible. Vérifiez vos informations" }` @ADyson is that good ? I'm sorry for the trouble I'm causing you ^^;

Comment: `$requete` is only your statement. It's not the actual data returned by the query. Therefore you can't compare that directly to the password. You need `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $cleMDP = $row["cleMDP"]; if (password_verify($_POST['motDePasse'], $cleMDP) == true)` ...etc. You already know how to get a row from a result, because you did it in your original code, so not sure why you didn't do it in that example. (Anyway you can work out if your code is "good" or not, by just testing it...)

Comment: @ADyson In a way, thank you because it indeed looks more secure, anyway, it still shows me the message when the informations are invalid. But I progressed a bit, so thanks. I also changed my form to only ask email and password, and swapped it to `POST` method. When I use `var_dump($_POST['motDePasse'], $cryptMDP)`, I'm getting the hashed password, but I also get NULL `String(60)`

Comment: Ok. Can you update the question with a) your HTML form, and b) the exact code you now have for the login process. Then we can see if there's anything else which still needs fixing. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. `$_POST['motDePasse']` won't exist, because in the form you have `name="mdp"` for the password field. You need to make sure the names match, the computer cannot guess your intentions. Please a) pay more attention to small details - they are important in programming, b) ensure you understand the basics of HTML forms, and c) learn how to [debug your code](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/) so you can do simple things like check if all the variables contain the values you expected - which will then help you to find the specific cause of a problem faster.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the advice. I'm still in studies about that, that's why I came here for (I think) basic stuff. That's the first time I tried to do a logging/signing system. Also yes, I have lack of attention for debugging my code. But yeah, thank you very much. It works !!

Comment: No problem. To be clear: debugging is a basic skill which every programmer needs to start learning almost as soon as they write their first program. I am continually astonished when I look at questions on this site that people attempt to write reasonably complex programs seemingly without having understood (or apparently even attempted to find out) anything about how they might go about testing them or detecting errors in them. You should be learning to debug from the first moment you learn how to program. Don't neglect this part of your knowledge, otherwise you won't ever solve small issues.